# TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.collection is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is my first time asking a question on StackOverflow. I am making a school project and I am a beginner at Firebase and JavaScript. I am trying to make a Tinder clone. React is telling me there's an error in this part of my code. At first I had different errors but they were Firebase syntax related and I promptly fixed them but now I don't have a clue on what this error means. My code works on localhost for a split second (I see my application) and then the error appears.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import TinderCard from 'react-tinder-card';
import database from './firebase';
import './SwipeCards.css';

...

function SwipeCards() {

...

useEffect(() => {
        database.collection('buddies').onSnapshot((snapshot) => setBuddies(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data())));
    }, []); 

...

}
```

I've tried two solutions of similar problems other people had, namely:
(in my tinderCards.js)

```
database.firestore().collection('buddies')...
```

and (in my firebase.js)

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

...

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
export default database;
```

But both didn't work. I can post more of the code if needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the new modular SDK (v9) which no longer uses `firebase.firestore()` namespace. I'd recommend following the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) to learn about new syntax:

```js
import database from './firebase';
import { doc, onSnapshot, collection, query, where } from "firebase/firestore";

useEffect(() => {
  const q = query(collection(db, "buddies"))
  const unsub = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
    console.log("Data", querySnapshot.docs.map(d => doc.data()));
  });
}, [])
```

Comment: Thank you the code works now, but could you explain to me what the 'const unsub' part is doing with the query and the 'console.log'?

Comment: @AnthonyNguyen `console.log()` is just logging the received data. The `unsub` function can be used if you want to stop the listener. Just call it as `unsub()` and the listener will stop receiving updates.

Comment: was this fix put into the firebase.js file? i have the same error but not seeing how this resolves it

Comment: @JamieGarcia the new Modular SDK uses a functional syntax like `collection(db, "col")` instead of `db.collection("col")` which was used before V8. You'll end up getting this error if you use older syntax while using V9+ of Firebase SDK.

Comment: so version 8.2.3 is the newer syntax?

Comment: @JamieGarcia no. The new syntax starts from `V9.0.0+`. Also if you are using any library such as rnfirebase or expo then you should make sure the version supports the Firebase JS SDK version that you are using. Also checkout more details about the new Modular SDK in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax:

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
//Get this from your firebase console
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();

export { db, auth };
```