# firestore.collection is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

this is my `firebase.js`

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getAnalytics, logEvent, isSupported } from "firebase/analytics";

//  Update the config
var firebaseConfig = {
  // ...Update config
 
};

// Initialize Firebase

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firestore = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth();
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

// Uncomment the following if you want to use emulator
// if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
//   firestore.useEmulator("localhost", 8080);
//   auth.useEmulator("http://localhost:9099");
// }

export { app, firestore, auth, analytics };
```

And this is how I am using it in one of my components-

```
import { app, firestore, auth } from "../../firebase";

  const linksPathRef = useMemo(
    () => firestore.collection("users").doc(userUid).collection("links"),
    [userUid]
  );
```

But I'm getting `firestore.collection is not a function` ERROR. Not sure, where I am going wrong.

firebase version that is installed in the project `"firebase": "^9.6.1"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: \_firebase\_\_WEBPACK\_IMPORTED\_MODULE\_2\_\_.default.collection is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68960910/typeerror-firebase-webpack-imported-module-2-default-collection-is-not-a-fu)

Comment: @Dharmaraj nope already tried that out. no luck.

Comment: You still have your code in name-spaced syntax (as in your question). Could you please share what you've tried from that answer?

Comment: can you please put that into perspective with respect to my code?

Comment: you are using the latest firebase SDK, that one does not longer support the dot notation instead it embraces functional programming. Please review the firebase docs carefully https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the commenters have pointed out, you're using the older API syntax while you're importing the v9 SDK.

The message is about this line

```
firestore.collection("users").doc(userUid).collection("links")
```

In the new modular syntax, that should be:

```
collection(firestore, "users", userUid, "links")
```

I recommend reading the Firestore documentation again, and checking out this [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this error as a NodeJS beginner with more Flutter familiarity.

I discovered my mistake today and I'd say it was from mistaking NodeJS syntax for Flutter syntax.

I was writing:

```
admin.firestore.collection('path-name').etcetera
```

What I should have written was:

```
admin.firestore().collection('path-name').etcetera
```

Leaving out the '()' gives the error message of this topic.

When I was close to resolving this error, the error message changed to 'firestore is not defined'.

Looking at your example above:

```
firestore.collection("users").doc(userUid).collection("links")
```

We made the same mistake.

Frank's answer helped me along and I would have co-signed it, but I couldn't find examples of the new modular call which featured the 'etcetera' aspect of my Firestore call.