# How to convert this Firebase v8 code to v9 code

Tags: reactjs, firebase

i am new to firebase v9 can anybody help me convert this code to import data from firebase collection-[firebase Collection Import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUQgr.png)

Comment: Same one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68960910

Comment: Please include code directly in the question. Links to screenshots are not searchable for people who may have the same question in future. Be kind to those who will follow you

Answer (score 0):

As per @Dharmaraj says on the link that he provides you may check this sample code below for v9. You may refer to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).

```
import database from './firebase';
import { doc, onSnapshot, collection, query, where, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";

    const [posts,setPosts] = useStat([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      const q = query(collection(db, "buddies"))
      const unsub = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
        console.log("Data", querySnapshot.docs.map(d => doc.data()));
      });
    }, [])
```